# Could not find gem in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile

Tags: ruby

```
jonsdirewolf:~/workspace $ bundle install
Could not find gem 'roo (~> 2.7.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

My gemfile:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
ruby "2.4.0" 
# gem "rails"
gem "mysql2"
gem "activerecord"  
gem 'byebug'
gem 'write_xlsx'
gem 'mechanize'
gem 'pry'
gem 'pry-byebug'
gem "roo", "~> 2.7.0"
```

What do I do?

Comment: This may not be the issue, but can you try `source "https://rubygems.org"`, with `https` instead of `http`?

Answer (score 1):

`rubygems.org` forces HTTPS:

```
> curl -I http://rubygems.org
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html
Location: https://rubygems.org/
```

and my hunch is that bundler may not follow the redirect.

So the fix would be to use

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
```

with "https" instead of "http".